# macOS recovery signing and checksums

Tags: partition, install, software-update, recovery, dmg

A question that has occupied me for a long time and I still haven't got the answer. It's about Apple's Internet Recovery.
When I read through quite a few pages from Apple, I saw that a signed .dmg was loaded into the recovery partition in order to protect against manipulated software, the same applies to Internet recovery.

Let's get to my question.

1. When the Mac loads the signed dmg file from the partition, it must say somewhere that the Mac should only take the dmg where the checksum is correct. Where is that listed? Has it been specially built into the hardware so that manipulation of the software, for example when system integration protection is deactivated, does not interest the Mac or is it a software issue? I ask myself the same question about Internet recovery.
2. Where is the software installation saved from the Internet?
3. Does the signing only apply using the methods mentioned above, or also with a boot stick?

Comment: For Q1, newer macs do indeed have a [security chip](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/security/secf020d1074/1/web/1).